# A process command in top

Tags: linux, bash, process, utilities, top-command

The problem comes up when you run couple of python scripts. in top at command, it shows only 'python' with these scripts. How to rename a process or otherwise tag it so that I could tell them apart in top?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Simply use the `--full-commands` option to show the full command line for each process :

```
top -c
```

Comment: is that GNU-top only? doesn't appear to work on OSX (assuming it uses BSD top?)

Answer (score 14):

Press "`c`" and display the command-line - that will allow you to see what they are.

Answer (score 4):

You might also check out the ps command.  Depending on your system:

```
ps aux
```

or

```
ps -fu USERNAME
```

Comment: It's like you're asking ps to say "Frak you USERNAME!" :-P

Answer (score 3):

Do you search for a way to display the full command line? Then simply press '`c`'

Answer (score 3):

This is probably going to be platform and version dependent, but on the platforms I use (CentOS, Debian), top normally displays the last part of the command run as the ID.

I'm guessing, therefore, that you're running your scripts by doing "python *scriptname*".

If you change your scripts to being executable as themselves (chmod +x and first line #!/usr/bin/python [or wherever python lives]), and then run them using just "*scriptname*" rather than "python *scriptname*", they should show up in top as their filename.

Comment: Also make sure you don't use "#!/usr/bin/env python" at the start of the script. Just use "#!/usr/bin/python".

Answer (score 1):

You can also try ps aux or ps -au USESRNAME. ps is quite nice since you can format the output, eg. ps -u USERNAME -o pid,command which would display pid and command of the process. Then you can also filter it through grep (ps -u USERNAME -o pid,command|grep python) to see all the running python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this in Python, but in C programs, argv[0] can actually be modified to show a "prettier" name for the process.  I think the constraint is that the new name has to be equal or shorter in length than the original name, such that you don't stomp on memory.